# Debug jar which was not compiled with debug flag

Tags: java, debugging, jar, ide, reverse-engineering

I got some java **.jar** that was not compiled with *debug* flag. I want to use them in remote debuggin via IDE, so i decompiled them and added as source to the project. Sometimes brake points works wrong or dont even work at all.

The question is, what's the best methodology to debug **.jar** files that was not compiled with `-g` flag.

Answer (score 2):

In case it is a maven dependency it might be the `-debug` artifact is distributed separately. For example this [HSQL](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.5.0/) dependency has both

- `hsqldb-2.5.0.jar`
- `hsqldb-2.5.0-debug.jar`

Unfortunately i didn't find a better way how to force IDE (Intellij IDEA) to download and use this artifact, so i downloaded it manually and replaces in *~/.m2/repository*:

`wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.5.0/hsqldb-2.5.0-debug.jar -O ~/.m2/repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.5.0/hsqldb-2.5.0.jar`

More info:

- [Java Debugging Deep Dive](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-java-debugging-deep-dive.html#141614d2)
- [Deploy an artifact with classifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you remote debug code that has undergone changes and the changes are not deployed to the remote device.  In a nutshell, the command in the jar does not correspond with the line number in your source.

Someone smarter than me might have a tricky answer, but for me the path of least resistance is to jar up the decompiled and then recompiled code from the jar file and debug that.

99.99% of the time I'm not interested in making actual changes to the jar so much as I simply want to know why my code doesn't work.  Once I'm past that hurdle, I'll drop the original jar back in place and make sure my code still works.  This a) (helps to make sure) that I don't violate the license, and b) doesn't make the project dependent on my code - since decompile/recompile can potentially change the behavior in subtle ways.

Be aware that some jar files have licenses such that simply decompiling the source and looking at it is a license violation.  Although I usually don't worry too much about that since I have no intention of permanently using the decompiled and recompiled code, I just need to "see" it for a while. :)

Comment: i got no plain source code. And when im recompiling jar im facing lots of errors. This software isnt mine, and licenced for sure, im just insterested in debugin it properly^^

Comment: I don't see how you can debug against the jar if you don't have a jar file where the line numbers in the class files match the line numbers in the java file.